# Getting id from a date object array with selection of day from a calendar

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a React Native app where I am using `react-native-calendar-picker`. Here, I have an array of objects containing values of different dates. The array is like this:

```js
[{id: 14, date: "2019-12-14", breakfast: 1, lunch: 0, dinner: 0},
{id: 15, date: "2019-12-15", breakfast: 0, lunch: 0, dinner: 1},
{id: 16, date: "2019-12-16", breakfast: 0, lunch: 0, dinner: 1}]
```

Now, i want the id value of this when I press on different dates. If the selected date does not matches any of the date from the array, the id value should be null. So, how can I check if my selected date value has ID or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```js
const date = '2019-12-14';
const array = [
  {id: 14, date: "2019-12-14", breakfast: 1, lunch: 0, dinner: 0},
  {id: 15, date: "2019-12-15", breakfast: 0, lunch: 0, dinner: 1},
  {id: 16, date: "2019-12-16", breakfast: 0, lunch: 0, dinner: 1}
];

const element = array.find(d => d.date === date);
const id = element ? element.id : null;

console.log(id);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I am storing the id to state to use this in a different function. But here in state, it's always getting the previous value. Can you tell me a workaround for that? @norbitrial